# Unity doesn't show always the score

Tags: unity, text, scoring

I don't know if this issue is in Unity or in my script, the score work well in scoreText, but in the scorePanel its show before last score like it showing 1 rather than 2; **the issue doesn't always appear its appear just in specific moment when my score++ and player die nearly in same time**, so here is my script.
AddToScore is called with InvokeRepeating, scoreText who show me the correct score, it works well

```
void AddToScore(){
    score++;
    scoreText.text = score.ToString ();
    mySound.Play();
}
```

This is when my player Die

```
void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D other)
{
    Time.timeScale = 0;
    Die ();
}

void Die (){
    Pause.SetActive (false);
    Panel.SetActive (true);
    GameOverPanel.SetActive (true);
    GenerateObstacles.HighScore ();
}
```

And here is the HighScore from GenerateObstacles

```
public void HighScore(){
    if (score > highScore) {
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt ("highScore", score);
        highScore = PlayerPrefs.GetInt ("highScore");
        scorePanel.text = score.ToString ();
        highScorePanel.text = highScore.ToString ();
    }
    else if (score <= highScore) {
        highScore = PlayerPrefs.GetInt ("highScore");
        scorePanel.text = score.ToString ();
        highScorePanel.text = highScore.ToString ();
    }
}
```

Here is a paint to understand

[image: score issue]

Comment: If somebody know how to resolve this issue, share it please :D

Answer (score 2):

When player dies, Time.timescale is set to zero. So, you are stopping your application's clock. So time doesn't pass and AddToScore() will not be invoked.

Comment: You didn't understand me right, AddToScore() is already invoked because the scoreText (in AddToScore()) have changed, but scorePanel (in HighScore()) isn't changed and I don't know why

Answer (score 0):

Looking at this:  `GenerateObstacles.HighScore ();` It's not clear how the class is designed. HighScore() is not declared static. It would look like GenerateObstacle is a static reference, but it is not. One way is to declare a static reference in GeneratedObstacles like this : 
`public static GeneratedObstacles current;` then, in Awake(),

`void Awake(){
current=this;
}`

With that, your code would change to : `GeneratedObstacles.current.HighScore();`

Comment: Thank you, but it didn't work, I always have the same problem, and what I don't understand why scorePanel doesn't change the value same to scoreText because they are using the same value